# Mapping rxjs response to class instances

Tags: angular

I am to display a list of Jobs within an Angular Material Table. Beforehand I used an interface IJob:

**job.interface.ts**

```
import { JobType } from "./job-type.interface";

export interface IJob {
    id: number;
    dateCreated?: Date;
    dateModified?: Date;
    userCreated?: string;
    ...
}
```

and in the job.component responsible for displaying the jobs I had this:

**job.component.ts**

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'jobType', 'dateStarted', 'status', 'completedPercentage', 'dateFinished', 'progressIcon', 'details'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IJob>();
  totalElements: number;
  .
  .
  .
  getJobs(page: number, pageSize: number) {
    this.jobsService.getAllJobs(page, pageSize)
    .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {
            this.dataSource.data = result.content;
          }
          this.totalElements = result.totalElements;
        }
      );
  }
```

But then I needed some logic to find out if the job has completed, is it stalled, is it completed unsuccessfully etc.. All that logic i had within the HTML in a *ngIf directive. So i thought I would create a Job class that implements this interface and define that logic there. That would mean I no longer have a dataSource of IJob, rather Job.

So now my question is, when I get the response, how do I create class instances and make a list of those instances to be my dataSource?

I tried this:

```
getJobs(page: number, pageSize: number) {
    this.jobsService.getAllJobs(page, pageSize)
    .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {
          for(let job of result.content) {
            let jobInstance = new Job(job.id, job.name, job.jobType, job.dateStarted, job.status,
              job.completedPercentage, job.dateFinished, job.isStalled, job.shouldTerminate, job.success);
            this.dataSource.data.push(jobInstance);
          }
          this.totalElements = result.totalElements;
        }
      );
  }
```

Now when I console log the dataSource, it's a list of Jobs

```
(13) [Job, Job, Job, Job, Job, Job, Job, Job, Job, Job, Job, Job, Job]
0: Job {id: 2, name: 'Job1', jobType: {…}, dateStarted: '2022-01-13T12:20:16.998+01:00', dateFinished: null, …}
1: Job {id: 6, name: 'Job5', jobType: {…}, dateStarted: '2022-01-13T12:20:16.998+01:00', dateFinished: '202 ...
```

but it doesn't display in the table. The mat-table in the HTML is empty..

**EDIT** The HTML Template

```
<div class="content-heading">
    <h2>{{ 'NAVBAR.JOBS' | translate }}</h2>
</div>

<div class="content-body">

    

    <div class="row buttons">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-left">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary shadow-sm mb-4" [routerLink]="['../']">
                {{ 'IMPORTS.ACTIONS.BACK' | translate }}
              </button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-right" (click)="refreshTable()">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info shadow-sm mb-4">
                {{ 'IMPORTS.ACTIONS.REFRESH' | translate }}
              </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <div class="loading-shade" *ngIf="isLoading">
              <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
        </div>

        <div class="table-container">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="w-100" matSort>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                    {{ 'JOBS.COLUMNS.NAME' | translate}}
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="jobType">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                    {{ 'JOBS.COLUMNS.JOB_TYPE' | translate}}
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.jobType.label}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="dateStarted">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                    {{ 'JOBS.COLUMNS.DATE_STARTED' | translate}}
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.dateStarted | date:'medium'}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                    {{ 'JOBS.COLUMNS.STATUS' | translate}}
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.status}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="completedPercentage">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                    {{ 'JOBS.COLUMNS.PROGRESS' | translate}}
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" 
                    matTooltip="{{element.completedPercentage * 100}}%"
                    matTooltipPosition="above">
                    <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="{{element.completedPercentage * 100}}"></mat-progress-bar>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="dateFinished">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                    {{ 'JOBS.COLUMNS.DATE_FINISHED' | translate}}
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.dateFinished | date:'medium'}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="progressIcon">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header></th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <mat-spinner *ngIf="element.dateFinished == null && !element.isStalled"
                     diameter="20">
                    </mat-spinner>
                    <mat-icon *ngIf="element.success && element.dateFinished != null">check</mat-icon>
                    <mat-icon *ngIf="!element.success && element.dateFinished != null">block</mat-icon>
                    <mat-icon *ngIf="element.isStalled">warning</mat-icon>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="details">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                    {{ 'JOBS.COLUMNS.DETAILS' | translate}}
                </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <p *ngIf="element.status_successful()">
                        Успешно
                    </p>
                    <p *ngIf="element.status_unsucessful()">
                        Неуспешно
                    </p>
                    <p *ngIf="element.status_stalled()">
                        Во застој
                    </p>
                    <p *ngIf="element.status_terminating()">
                        Се прекинува
                    </p>
                    <p *ngIf="element.status_terminated()">
                        Прекинато
                    </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="stopJob(element)"
                     *ngIf="element.status_inProgress()">
                        Прекини
                    </button>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <mat-paginator [pageSize]="paginatorPageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" [length]="totalElements"
        (page)="onPageChange($event)"></mat-paginator>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the template you can see something like `*ngIf = 'element.status_successful()'` Before adding the logic in the Job class I had to write something like `*ngIf='element.dateCompleted !== null && element.status != 'complted' && ...'` so that was very bad to look at.

Now I put that logic in the `status_successul()` method.

Comment: Would you mean to include the template as well, I think it could be useful

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).